# How to get the key ID from a .pem openssl file?

Tags: openssl, rsa, amazon-web-services

I have a .pem private key generated by openssl. 
How to extract the key ID from it?

Edit: the generated rsa keypair is for Amazon cloudfront. When uploaded on the console, a 'Key ID' is displayed. However the private key I have generated is not for my account and I don't have any slot available to upload the public key on my AWS account (there's a limit of 2 public keys).

Comment: Is there any specific program that requires you to enter such a key ID?

Comment: @user1686 In my use case, I am trying to recover cert/key relationships in an unfamiliar PKI environment. It would be easier if I could look at what's there and confirm relationships using these IDs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Bare keys do not have "key IDs". They're just series of numbers.

If the key belongs to an X.509 certificate, then the certificate's fingerprint (a SHA-1 hash of the DER-encoded cert) will be used for identification: `openssl x509 -outform der | openssl sha1`, or `openssl x509 -noout -fingerprint`.

Otherwise (if it's just a bare public/private keypair), the SHA-1 hash of the *public* key  is used sometimes (again, DER encoding), but I don't know of any standard for it. You can extract the public key with `openssl rsar -pubout -outform der`, again piping to `openssl sha1` if that's what your program requires.

---

The "key pair IDs" used by CloudFront are serial numbers of the *database entry* with that key. The same key, uploaded twice, will have different IDs; I just tested it.

Comment: thanks. I have edited my question. It looks like the way to generate this AWS 'key ID' is proprietary, so my question is just plain wrong...

Comment: CloudFront key IDs are indeed proprietary; see updated answer.

Comment: Try using the ```-sha256``` option. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55847788/how-does-aws-iot-generate-a-certificate-id for details.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon now provides tools for performing such actions on any server (not just servers running in EC2). On any Ubuntu computer you can install the tools with `apt-get`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ec2-ami-tools ec2-api-tools
```

Here is the syntax to get the fingerprint for `My.pem`:

```
$ ec2-fingerprint-key My.pem
62:44:56:f7:91:f2:8b:9b:44:7c:17:0e:39:c7:34:68:f5:b2:3c:57
```

As `ec2-fingerprint-key` is a bit long to type, there is an equivalent shortcut `ec2fp`:

```
$ ec2fp My.pem
62:44:56:f7:91:f2:8b:9b:44:7c:17:0e:39:c7:34:68:f5:b2:3c:57
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below command to get KID/fingerprint

```
openssl x509 -in <certificate_file> -fingerprint -noout|cut -f2 -d '='| tr -d ':'
```

Answer (score -1):

The kid does have a standard behind it, but some options are left to the client, which is why the client has a responsibility to maintain it https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.2